# Display "true" checkboxinput in django

Tags: python, django, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to display some checkbox in a form after getting the data from my database.
I have some fields that set if something is public or not. The checkbox are always 'unchecked'.

my class:

```
class PrivacyForm(forms.Form):
    geburtsdatum=forms.CheckboxInput()
    strasse=forms.CheckboxInput()
    plz=forms.CheckboxInput()
    ort=forms.CheckboxInput()
    land=forms.CheckboxInput()
    fon=forms.CheckboxInput()
```

my method:

```
@login_required
def edit_privacy(request,template_name='user/edit_privacy.html'):
    user=Users.objects.get(id_u=request.user.id)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=PrivacyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        #
            render_to_response('user/public_profil.html',{'profil':user},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            msg="make sure all fields are entered and valid"
    else:
    #form
        form=PrivacyForm()
        msg="Select what you want to be public"

    return render_to_response(template_name,{'form':form,'profil':user,'msg':msg},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my form:

```
{% extends "home/portal.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h3>::::: PRIVATSPHÄRE :::::</h3>
{{msg}}
<form id="formSearch" action="/user/privacy/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Speichern" class="button"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand how you use this form, but this will work:

```
class PrivacyForm(forms.Form):
    geburtsdatum=forms.BooleanField()
    strasse=forms.BooleanField()
    plz=forms.BooleanField()
    ort=forms.BooleanField()
    land=forms.BooleanField()
    fon=forms.BooleanField()
```

And then in the view code, you can set initial values:

```
 form=PrivacyForm(initial={'geburtsdatum': True,
                           'strasse': True,...})
```

which will render the specified checkboxes as checked(if 'True') or unchecked(if 'False')..

Comment: @blfuentes: Tisho hit the nail on the head. `forms.CheckboxInput` is a *widget*, not a form field. You have to use `forms.BooleanField`, which uses `forms.CheckboxInput` as its default widget.

Answer (score 1):

you could check it here!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

```
class  PrivacyForm(models.Model):
       pass

form = PrivacyForm(object_provacy_model_item)
```